# What is the best approach for a Workflow Intranet site and a links list internet site on SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

New to SharePoint 2013.  A bit struggling on what approach/model should be taken on a workflow intranet site and a link list internet site.  App, NCSS or SP Solution?  Here's some info.  Any suggestion would be appreciated.

We do have on-premises server, still in testing mode.

The workflow site must use Active Directory for authentication.  Can recreate order item list.  Item may have different pricing at different time.  Must be able to keep history of submitted order for delivery and for record.  Trigger of email for approval, modification and resubmit, marked for partial or full delivery.  May integrate with Excel/Office but not necessarily, depending on pros and cons.

The links list internet site is for anonymous access and Active Directory users access.  There will be some pages for AD user only.  Links will be stored as list.  Branding is important on this one.  Must be able to fully manipulate layout and effect.  Option to allow some rating or social features would be nice though not critical.

Will be happy to receive any feedback and provide clarification.

K